# Código jQuery não funciona como deve com slideToggle porquê?

Tags: jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>FAQ | jQuery Essentials</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 10%;
        }

        .button {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            background: #09f;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .button:hover {
            background: #069;
        }

        .fade {
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        }

        .fade_box {
            width: 500px;
            background: white;
            max-width: 96%;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .fade_close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5%;
            right: 5%;
            color: #eee;
            font-size: 2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .fade_close:hover {
            color: #bf7676;
        }

        .fade_box p {
            padding: 10px;
            background: #eee;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0;
            color: #777;
        }

        .fade_box p:hover {
            color: black;
        }

        .fade_box p b {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-left: 30px;
            opacity: 0.5;
            padding: 2px 7px;
            background: #069;
            color: white;
            font-size: .7em;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 10%;
        }

        .slide {
            background: #eee;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .slide:first-of-type {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .slide * {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .slide h4 {
            font-size: 0.875em;
            font-weight: 500;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 0;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .slide h4:hover {
            background: #fbfbfb;
        }

        .slide_content {
            background: #000;
            color: white;
            display: none;
            padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
        }

        .slide_content p {
            font-size: .8em;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<span class="expand button">Expanded ALL</span> | <span class="close button">Close All</span> | <span class="toggle button">Toggle All</span>

<div class="slide">
    <h4>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</h4>
    <div class="slide_content">
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide">
    <h4>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</h4>
    <div class="slide_content">
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide">
    <h4>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</h4>
    <div class="slide_content">
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
        <p>Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshiLorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi Lorem iihdshi  Lorem iihdshi</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    const speed = 500;

    $(".expand").on("click", function () {
        $(".slide_content").stop().slideDown(speed, function () {

        });
    });

    $(".close").on("click", function () {
        $(".slide_content").stop().slideUp(speed, function () {

        });
    });

    $(".toggle").on("click", function () {
        $(".slide_content").stop().slideToggle(speed, function () {

        });
    });

    $(".slide h4").on("click", function () {
        // $(this).parent().find(".slide_content").slideToggle(); para n fechar todos automaticamente quando abre um
        $(".slide_content").stop().slideUp(speed);
        $(this).parent().find(".slide_content").slideToggle();
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou com dúvida no seguinte trecho do cód jQuery:

```
 $(".slide h4").on("click", function () {
    // $(this).parent().find(".slide_content").slideToggle(); para n fechar todos automaticamente quando abre um
    $(".slide_content").stop().slideUp(speed);
    $(this).parent().find(".slide_content").slideToggle();
});
```

Este trecho de código deveria fazer o box de texto abrir e fechar (quando clica no h4 titulo de cada uma das 3 seções), contudo somente abre, quando clico para fechar ele contrai e expande imediatamente ficando sempre aberto